# Allow users to add custom functions to wordpress theme

Tags: theme-development, functions

I'd like to allow users to add functions to the theme I'm developing, but don't want users to change functions.php directly, as this file may be updated with theme updates. In other words, I'd like this to work in a similar fashion to custom CSS files.

How can I setup a user-functions.php file for users and ensure those functions are also run when the theme is activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part). I think that is the closest you can get to what you want.

You may be able to just drop `get_template_part('userfuncts');` into your `functions.php`. That will load `userfuncts.php` from your theme's main directory, if the file is present, or from a child theme's directory if applicable. See the Codex for how the function searches for files. It is a stepped-up version of PHP's `include` really. Any function that would work in `functions.php` should work in that included file. But that is an important condition. Some things do not load well from a theme's `functions.php` and need to be in a plugin.

However, EAMann has a good point. While it is possible to update the theme without losing the `userfuncts.php` file, that is not necessarily the case. It is fairly common to completely delete a theme and then upload the update. I don't know how the automatic updater does this, as I never use that updater, but if it deletes and then reinstalls you are going to have trouble.

You could do something like create two directories for your theme-- the main one and a second user functions directory.

- wp-content/themes/my-theme
- wp-content/themes/my-theme-userfuncts

Then create a `get_template_part`-like function to load files from that directory. It shouldn't be hard to do using `get_template_part` as a model. You'd  have a kind of pseudo-child theme. It could be a source of confusion but good docs would help a lot and I have no idea how 'proper' that solution is. I only just thought about it. Hope I don't get yelled at :)

Your theme could just install itself and a child but the you'd have the same update issue if you ever altered the child.

Comment: "*Then create a `get_template_part`-like function to load files from that directory...*" Might I suggest [**`locate_template()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template)?

Comment: ['locate_template`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/template.php#L368), if I am not mistaken, will look inside the current theme for the file, not outside of it which is key to this. At least, I couldn't get the syntax right to make either `get_template_part` or `locate_template` look **outside** the current theme folder to grab a file. If you know how to do that, then yes, that would be preferable.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: Appreciate your response. I think you've gotten the closest to what I need. I'm planning to have a separate directory for custom user stuff and I was thinking about using PHP's include. I'm going to accept and upvote your answer.

Comment: `get_template_part()` is just a wrapper for `locate_template()`. You can tell `locate_template()` where to look. ;) **@chowwy**: caveat: if that directory is inside your own Theme, it will get removed when the Theme is updated. **Nothing** in the Theme itself is safe/update-proof for the end user to edit.

Comment: @ChipBennett, `locate_template` uses the constants `STYLESHEETPATH` and `TEMPLATEPATH`. Those point to either the child or the parent theme directory-- `var_dump(STYLESHEETPATH,TEMPLATEPATH);`-- and they are hard coded into `locate_template`. It does not appear meant to load files from outside of one of those two locations, ***which is what I am suggesting that the asker do***. If you know how to do that, I'd love to know. I will edit my answer and thank you for it. I am not suggesting the asker create an actual child theme for this, if that is what you are thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Really, any files you place in the theme will be replaced/removed when the theme updates.

Instead, if you want users to add custom functionality they should do so through a custom plugin.  If you have hooks and filters exposed through the theme, a custom functionality plugin will solve the problem.

Basically, it's two files:

### readme.txt

```
=== My Functionality Plugin ===
Contributors:      me
Donate link:
Tags:
Requires at least: 3.4.2
Tested up to:      3.5
Stable tag:        1.0
License:           GPLv2 or later
License URI:       http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

Adds custom functionality where needed
```

### functionality.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Functionality Plugin
 * Plugin URL:
 * Description: Adds custom functionality where needed
 * Version:     1.0
 * Author:      Me
 * Author URI:  
 * License:     GPL2+
 */

function filter_my_theme_copyright( $copyright ) {
    return '&copy; 2013';
}
add_filter( 'my_theme_copyright', 'filter_my_theme_copyright' );
```

Without knowing what your theme is doing or what custom functionality you need, I can't be very precise.  But if you expose actions where you want users to *do* something and filter what output you want them to filter, then anyone can use a custom functionality plugin like this without hacking on the theme directly.

Comment: Thanks. I already know how to setup a custom functions file in a plugin. I would prefer to build this directly into my theme, so that users can simply edit the user-functions.php file and the functions will be active with the theme.

Comment: If `user-functions.php` is part of your theme, it will be wiped out when they upgrade.  The exact same problem you're trying to avoid by not having them edit `functions.php` itself. The only way to allow persistent user-specified functionality is to move it *out* of the theme itself. Or to have them build a child theme of your theme with its own functionality.

Comment: Not necessarily. I've noticed similar custom functions functionality in the thesis theme and didn't encounter any loss of code when upgrading the theme. Just like custom CSS files don't change when a theme is upgraded.

Comment: As far as I know, Thesis doesn't use the core updater; users have to update it manually. That's not a model I would choose to emulate. YMMV.

Comment: Not interested in emulating Thesis' model, just want to make it as convenient as possible for users to add functions to my theme.

Answer (score 2):

For allowing user *functions*, you really have two options:

1. Make your Theme as **Child Theme-friendly** as possible, and encourage users to define custom functions in the Child Theme `functions.php`
2. Provide ample action/filter hooks, for the user to define callback functions, either via Child Theme, or via custom Plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm planning to use the hooks, just not in a plugin or child theme.

Comment: What do you mean by, "not in a plugin or child theme"? Presumably, you would *define* your hooks, and the *user* would **add callbacks** to your *Theme-defined* hooks.

Comment: I meant that I want to allow users to add their functions to the theme without using a plugin or child theme.

Comment: Impossible. **Anything** an end user adds to your Theme will be removed/overwritten when the Theme is updated. WordPress physically deletes the current Theme directory, then unpacks the new Theme to put in its place. Files are deleted then written, not simply overwritten-in-place.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that allows you to do this in the admin, it allows for portable user input functions (theme agnostic) , with no need to edit to your theme's functions.php

You can see it here: https://github.com/bungeshea/code-snippets

You can download it from wordpress.org here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/code-snippets/

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Would rather not use a plugin for theme functionality.

Comment: If the code is tied into a specific theme's functionality then yes, otherwise think about abstracting the code for portability.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure your customers are able to easily override aspects of your theme, the best bet is to stick with WordPress' existing conventions for this, ie: a child theme. "functions.php" is also intended for custom user-entered code, but you said you'd prefer to stay away from that, so I'll focus on other options.

The general rule of thumb is as follows:

**Styles**

Overriding CSS styles should be done in the "style.css" file inside a child theme.

**Functions**

Overriding procedural functions should be done using pluggable functions. The WordPress Codex has an example of [how to setup pluggable functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions).

**Hooked Functions**

While functions that are assigned to a hook or filter could also be made pluggable, you could also just encourage customers to unhook the function and hook in their own replacement. This would save you, at most, 2 lines of code per function in your files, as you wouldn't be making the functions pluggable.

**Template Parts**

If you'd like customers to be able to easily override specific sections of your theme's output without having to copy an entire template file into their child theme, you could make effective use of template parts to achieve this (for example, if your footer area contains widgets and then, maybe, a credits section, each of those could be a template part).

As mentioned above, effective placement of `do_action()` calls is an easy way to allow customers to hook in their own code.

Combined with the above options, you should be well on your way to having your customers easily customise your theme using existing WordPress conventions and making it easier for them to update their copy of your theme to future versions. :)